# User Made Videos on iPhone 4S

Tags: video, iphone, user-account

When I sync my iPhone 4S to my PC, I'm able to transfer pictures to my PC drive to make more room on my iPhone.

Why can't I transfer user made videos to my PC? The user made videos take up more space than my pictures and so I would like to free up some space for other save data.

Is it possible to transfer user made videos to a PC? If so, how?

Comment: It's got to be possible, but I'll admit I don't know how, because I don't have a Windows computer to check with. Did you look at the sync settings in iTunes? That's often key.

Comment: I find this surprising. My Windows machine allows me to import videos using the built-in Windows 7 camera import wizard. What OS are you running? What applications have you tried?

Comment: Daniel, I have not look at the sync settings of iTunes yet, but I will soon. On this note, I don't have to sync to iTunes to transfer my photos from my iPhone 4S to my PC hard drive...a command option just pops up asking me what I want to do. Thus, no connection to iTunes needed.

Comment: @Randolph, I'm currently running iOS 5.1 and have not tried any application to transfer the user made videos files off my iPhone 4S. So, what and where can I find this built-in camera wizard in Window-7?

Comment: I plug in my phone, using the USB cable. Up pops the wizard to ask me whether I'd like to import my photos and videos from the iPhone. I click "Yes". It asks me how I want to label the import. I type in a label, it appends the date, and that's that. Here's a link to what I see: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a walk-through for importing pictures and videos to Windows Vista and Windows 7, here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083.